# Which is the best module to import/export automatically with cron

Tags: product, customer, import, cron, export

I am looking for a module which can permit me import & export by creating or updating if exist already :

```
- product
- customer
- stock
- attributes of product (import only)
- categories (import only)
```

Using a cron for importation and exportation.
Can you advice me for the best module import/export update and create with cron compatible with Magento 1.9 and version 2

Thanks

Comment: Have you taken a look at Magmi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out.
http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

You can configure it to run from cron.

Comment: Upvote the answer  please if you find it usefull. You can ask more about i built an app that synced magento through magmi.